# How to proxy an anonymous function so that both "this" keywords are available?

Tags: jquery

I would like to use the `jQuery.proxy` method to provide a context for an anonymous function. At the same time I would like the context of the proxied original function to be available.

Consider this example:

```
example.find("li").each($.proxy(function(i) {
    var context = this; // Great! This gives me the context of the function call as expected.
    var $li = '???'; // How can I access the jQuery element of the <li>? $(this) obviously won't do.
}, this));
```

How would I access the iterated `<li>` elements here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the second parameter to the `.each`callback

```
example.find("li").each($.proxy(function(i, el) {
    var context = this; // Great! This gives me the context of the function call as expected.
    var $li = $(el);
}, this));
```

See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/) for `.each()`

Answer (score 0):

I use the following method:

```
var self = this;
example.find("li").each(function() {
    var $li = $(this); // this is the <li>
    self.someMethod(); // self is the context
});
```

Comment: That is actually what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: Why? This construct is called a *closure* and is idiomatic JS.

Comment: I am trying to avoid `that`, `self`, `me`, etc. for readability and to keep control over the context. However, this is mostly a matter of conviction and is case-dependent.